# How to keep current_locale when sending email with ActiveJob and Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I am using Active_job and sidekiq to send emails asynchronously. But my current_locale is lost when performing the email sending. I set the I18n.locale by the url patterns of every request.

I used to use Sidekiq, which provide a  [plugin](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/middleware/i18n.rb) to store the current_locale, and use it when sending.

But I am now upgrading to Rails 4.2.1, ActiveJob seems it doesn't provide a solution like this.

Any thought?

One way I know is to pass the current_locale as an argument to mailer, then use I18n.with_locale {... }, but this would change many places...

Comment: It should work if you activate the i18n middleware and are still using Sidekiq as your ActiveJob provider. Did you switch to some other provider?

Comment: Yes. It works with Sidekiq.  Previously it was caused by wrong translations(I should do more checks). Now it is ok.  Thanks!